# fastest way to change key of a table value

Tags: json, performance, lua, lua-table

> **TL;DR** I'm searching the most performant way to change the keys of a lua-table where all indices are numeric.

I've got a web-service on an micro-processing-unit, written in Lua.

This service is receiving an array as JSON of the following structure where the object itself will be used by lua after being parsed from JSON to lua-table.

> JSON

```
[ 
 [
  [a,b,c],[d,e,f]
 ],[
  [g,h,i],[j,k,l]
 ]
]
```

> Lua Table

```
parsedJSON = { [1] = {
                [1] = { [1] = a, [2] = b, [3] = c },
                [2] = { [1] = d, [2] = e, [3] = f }
               }, 
               [2] = {
                [1] = { [1] = g, [2] = g, [3] = i },
                [2] = { [1] = j, [2] = k, [3] = l }
               } 
}
```

Looking at the indices of a|b|c, they're:

```
parsedJSON[1][1][1] = a
parsedJSON[1][1][2] = b
parsedJSON[1][1][3] = c
```

Everything fine so far. But the deepest indices aren't what the web-service excepts. Lua-site here doesn't except 1/2/3 as index but 1/9/17.

Like this:

```
parsedJSON[1][1][1] = a
parsedJSON[1][1][9] = b
parsedJSON[1][1][17] = c
```

Due the service is running on a MPU, computing power is very limited and I want to know the most performant way to change this keys.

A simple pairs loop is surely a effective solution, but not efficient.
I guess there's some way using metatable, isn't it?

Edit:

The structure will not change and is fix.
May it a good way to refer from idx[9] to idx[2] and from [17] to[3] and leave the table as it is?

Comment: Is the JSON also fixed or can you change that? If you can, why not just post `{ 1: "a", 9: "b", 17: "c" }` instead? However, you **can** use a metatable if you really want, but you'll have to apply it to the innermost tables: `{ __index = function(t, k) if k == 9 then return t[2] elseif k == 17 then return t[3] end end }`. It's just not as maintainable as other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Metatables aren't a solution for performance, just for usability. Reordering would be the fast solution by taking the reference of the most inner table and then moving the values there. Set the old fields to nil, so the internal array can shrink and less memory is in use.

Answer (score 0):

i cannot test it now, but imo there can be used a variant of normal table.insert() of the element to [x][y] where index number 0 (which is normaly not used) will hold a table where you will add number of the index for json {1,9,17} and normal indexes will be incremented automatically that means

```
[1][1][0] = {1,9,17}
[1][1][1] = 100
[1][1][2] = 900
[1][1][3] = 1700
```

now if you need ie value of JSON index 1.1.9 you need to check field [1][1][0] with ipairs (i,v) for that value (v) and store its index (i). then you simply get value from [1][1][i]. there you should be able to also remove or simply modify those values and prevent their duplicity or overwriting

maybe not simpliest way how to doit but probably most safest and understandable for debugging